# DynamoDb: Query items between two dates

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I'm not having much luck with this query, it returns 0 items

```
const { Items } = await this.dynamoDb.query({
  TableName: 'exampleTableName',
  IndexName: 'createdDateTime-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#createdDateTime BETWEEN :fromDateTime AND :toDateTime AND #status = :status',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#status': 'status',
    '#createdDateTime': 'createdDateTime',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':fromDateTime': '2017-02-20T01:58:49.710Z',
    ':toDateTime': new Date().toISOString(),
    ':status': 'SUCCESS',
  },
}).promise();
```

I have one item in the DB:

```
{
  "id": "fa47003a-983a-4dc3-a87e-ace73ea7e451",
  "createdDateTime": "2018-02-20T02:58:49.710Z",
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Table:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
  --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 \
  --table-name exampleTableName \
  --attribute-definitions \
    AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=status,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=createdDateTime,AttributeType=S \
  --key-schema \
    AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
  --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10 \
  --global-secondary-indexes \
    IndexName=createdDateTime-index,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=status,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=createdDateTime,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}"
```

I would expect 2018-02-20T02:58:49.710Z to fall between 2017-08-30T03:11:22.627Z and now.

Can you help out with the query?

Comment: What is the full item in the table? The one you show isn't correct, it lacks the `id` attribute?

Comment: Sorry @cementblocks Added the missing id field to the data sample

Comment: Your query works for me, using your table definition and object. Are you hitting the local endpoint in your nodejs code?

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work for me then. It does now. Must have something to do with my local setup...

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below code and it works as expected:

```
const { Items } = await this.dynamoDb.query({
  TableName: 'myTable',
  IndexName: 'myIndex',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#createdDateTime BETWEEN :fromDateTime AND :toDateTime AND #status = :status',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#status': 'status',
    '#createdDateTime': 'createdDateTime',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':fromDateTime': '2017-02-20T01:58:49.710Z',
    ':toDateTime': new Date().toISOString(),
    ':status': 'SUCCESS',
  },
}).promise();
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.